# react drag and drop list item

Tags: reactjs, drag-and-drop, draggable

I've been researching a way to drag and drop list items and found a few like React Beautiful DND and React Draggable, but what I want is to drag and drop a list item over another and create a nested list with both list items inside is there a package that does that or should I use one of those packages and implement the logic my self

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I stumbled upon your question and I have made a very basic npm package which might solve what you are asking for. This package implements basic drag and drop functionality with events on drag and on drop only (no logic for actually moving the elements). Maybe it helps you. Here is a link to the repository with example code:

https://github.com/githubjonas/react-tiny-drag-drop

Answer (score 0):

you can use sortableJs for a nested list here its reference link:
https://sortablejs.github.io/Sortable/#nested